# Microsoft Word: never save personal information

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

There is a button in Word Document Properties at the bottom of the Details tab: "Remove Properties and Personal information".

I got tired of clicking on it, then saving a copy, then renaming it back (it is anyway easier than clicking on all checkboxes).

Is there an option to make Word never save "properties and personal information"?

---

I really want to remove properties from the Origin section, i.e.

- Authors
- Last saved by
- Revision number
- Version number
- Company
- Manager

but I will not complain if a solution also removes other properties, such as

- Title
- Subject
- Tags
- Categories
- Comments
- Content status
- Content type
- Language

Answer (score 1):

The option of saving personal properties & information is most likely linked with the "Normal.dot" template that Word 2010 uses for all documents.

As I am not sure what Personal properties or information you are wishing to strip from all documents you are creating, but if it is just your name, you should be able to remove this through "Word options" located in File >> Options >> General.

When at this window, you can remove your "User name" and "Initials" from these fields (or insert a blank space).

If that does not work, please provide more detail in your original question as to what information you wish to remove from your documents.

Comment: I think that the "Last saved by" property has nothing common with "Normal.dot".